# How does the intracluster replication on couchbase work?

Tags: couchbase

How does the intracluster replication on couchbase work?
I understood that the buckets that contains the documents, are subdivided in vbuckets. 
The vbuckets also create their replicas to provide High Availability,and the master vbucket and the replicas are stored in different servers throughout the cluster. Now I wanted to understand how is the process of sending the copies to the replicas done? With MongoDB we have oplogs, what about in couchbase?

Answer (score 2):

Couchbase Server uses [Distributed Change Protocol](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/dcp-documentation) (DCP) for intracluster and intercluster replication.

From [Couchbase Distributed Data Management](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/concepts/distributed-data-management.html) documentation:

> [DCP is] a high-performance streaming protocol that communicates the state of the data using an ordered change log with sequence numbers.

The Couchbase Forums have [some commentary](https://forums.couchbase.com/t/question-on-couchbase-replication/7879/2?u=jkurtz) on the replication process in the face of node failures.

DCP facilitates many Couchbase integrations such as the [Kafka Connector](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/connectors/kafka-3.2/kafka-intro.html). See the [Connector Guides](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/connectors/intro.html) for more examples.

Comment: Adding a link to a presentation done on DCP right after it was released (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j5T7wELj9Wc) which goes through the core concepts.

Comment: Thanks for the link, @mikewied.